# How not to aggregate on numeric fields

Tags: sql, ssms

I have this code with which I am trying not to aggregate on two columns `HistoryQuantity` and `TOTFCST`. I keep getting this error

> Column 'SCPOMGR.HISTWIDE_CHAIN.HistoryQuantity' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

I don't think I should group by numeric columns.

Is there any way around this?

```
-- WAPE (chain)
SET ARITHABORT OFF 
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF

SELECT 
    b.[LOC], b.[DMDUNIT], 
    ABS(b.HistoryQuantity - a.TOTFCST) AS 'Abs Error',    
    SUM(b.HistoryQuantity) AS 'Sum of Actuals',
    SUM(ABS((b.HistoryQuantity - a.TOTFCST)))  AS 'Sum of Abs Error', 
    SUM(ABS((b.HistoryQuantity - a.TOTFCST))) / SUM(b.HistoryQuantity) AS 'WAPE'
FROM 
    SCPOMGR.FCSTPERFSTATIC a
JOIN 
    SCPOMGR.HISTWIDE_CHAIN b ON a.[STARTDATE] = b.[DMDPostDate] 
                             AND a.[DMDUNIT] = b.[DMDUNIT] 
                             AND a.[LOC] = b.[LOC]
GROUP BY 
    b.[LOC], b.[DMDUNIT], b.[DMDPostDate]
ORDER BY 
    b.[LOC]
```

Comment: If you have a GROUP BY clause then every column in your SELECT clause either needs to be in your GROUP BY or use an aggregate function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ABS() is not an aggregate function and cannot be used without, for example, passing aggregate values to it

use any like this

```
 ABS(Sum(b.HistoryQuantity) - Sum(a.TOTFCST))
```

Comment: I have a question. Is there any difference if it is ABS(Sum(b.HistoryQuantity) - Sum(a.TOTFCST)) or SUM(ABS(b.HistoryQuantity - a.TOTFCST)) ?

Comment: Mathematically it will give the same result
That is, there is no difference in this case, and you can test it

Comment: Rami Bancosly thank you.